# Can the count data be used to calculate Kernel Density Estimate?

Tags: density-function, count-data, kernel-smoothing

I have the number of amino acids in cytoplasmic domain for enzymes and non-enzymes for CD proteins.

I want to generate a probability density distribution for enzymes and non-enzymes using their number of amino acids in cytoplasmic domain. I think the number of amino acids is a discrete variable (count data). In that case, can I use kernel density estimation to calculate the probability density for enzyme and non-enzymes?

[image]

My goal is to compare distributions and determine whether at a certain amino acid count (for example, 200) a CD protein will be more likely enzyme or non-enzyme. Also, I want to statistically determine how much likely it will be non-enzyme compared with enzyme in terms of probability.

I calculated kernel mass estimation using associated kernel estimation (Ake) package in R. However, my problem is I could not determine the probability of a CD protein with all cytoplasmic length from 0 to 1090. This becomes a huge problem for me because I am trying to predict the probability at any positive integer points from 1 to 1098 and beyond.

Here are the kernel mass functions for enzyme and non-enzyme.

[image]
[image]

Comment: You **can** feed such data to a density estimation routine and the results **may** help in visualizing the distributions. The harder question is what you think you are doing thereby. As you say, the distributions are discrete and density estimation won't help you beyond seeing broad features here. Your problem is evidently to predict enzyme or not from amino acid count; that's a smoothing of a (0,1) response at an exploratory level and a logistic regression at a modelling level. Whether extrapolating any such model makes sense is a subject-matter question on which I cannot advise.

Comment: At intermediate level, probability density is defined only for continuous variables and not for discrete variables and it's just wrong or confused to attribute density to a discrete variable. The distinction is between probability density functions and probability mass functions. ("Probability density distributions" is not a standard term.) At a more advanced level, probability theorists who know a lot of measure theory (not me) seem happy with terminology such as density with respect to counting measure.

Comment: The term "kernel mass function" also sounds odd to me but I am not familiar with the package you have used (and not experienced with R).

Comment: It seems that you have only about 26 enzymes (1/26 $\approx$ 0.038). I trust it's clear that that is a small sample to get at any distribution.

Comment: @Nick Cox . Thank you for giving me a good suggestion. I think logistic regression would be a better choice to predict the probability of obtaining enzyme or non-enzyme at any particular Amino acid count. You mentioned "You can feed **such data to a density estimation routine** and the results may help in visualizing the distributions". The first figure that I have posted is the Kernel Density Estimation. Do you think that I can use my count data to plot the kernel density estimation?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand the question. You've done it, so "can you do it?" is already known and "can" was answered in my first comment. If you're asking if such a graph is publishable or acceptable in your field, you need to ask around; I am not any kind of biologist. I would never publish a similar graph in a statistical journal. because there is no density function (narrow sense) underlying the data. As we're using English, the nuanced differences between can, may and should are central to knowing what you mean.

Comment: Thank you Nick. I am clear now about when to use probability density function. You comments are great help.